# How to solve the sql errno: '1064' and ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-error-1064

I have the following code which contains few sql queries:

```
createNewOrder: (data,callBack) => {
     

        pool.query(
            
            `Insert into ordering (supplycontract) values (?)`,
            [
              data.supplierId
            ],
            (error,results,fields) => {
                if(error){
                   return callBack(error)
                }
                pool.query(
                    `select id from ordering order by id desc limit 1`, 
                    [
                        data.articleId
                    ],
                    (error,results1,fields) =>{
                        if(error){
                            return callBack(error)
                        }
                        let orderid = results1[0].id;
                        console.log(orderid);

                        pool.query(
                            `Insert into position (quantity,delivery,ordering,positioninorder,articlecontract) values(?,?,?,1,?)`,
                            [
                                data.quantity,
                                new Date(),
                                orderid,
                                data.articleId 
                            ],
                            (error,results3,fields) => {
                                if(error){
                                    callBack(error)
                                 }
                                 //callBack(null,results3)
                            }

                        );
                    }

                );
                return callBack(null,results)
            }
        );
    }
```

I tried several tricks and to improve the code but unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'position (quantity,delivery,ordering,positioninorder,articlecontract) values(54,' at line 14
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'position (quantity,delivery,ordering,positioninorder,articlecontract) values(54,' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "Insert into position (quantity,delivery,ordering,positioninorder,articlecontract) values(54,'2021-07-11 19:18:39.334',16,1,5)"
}

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
 code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

Comment: `return callBack(null, results)` should be inside the callback function of the last query

Comment: Thanks! That helped me to solve the second error of HTTP_Headers but still the SQL syntax error is there.  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR', errno: 1064. The queries appear ok to me though.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return on your database server? I tested your insert statement on a MySQL 8.0.23 instance. It did not report any syntax error (it did give an error because I don't have a table named position, but that means it at least got past the syntax checking).

Comment: My version is MySQL 8.0.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues

1. `return callBack(null,results)` should come inside the callback of 3rd query.
2. `callBack(error)` in the error handler of 3rd query should have return statement like `return callBack(error)`.
3. SQL error: This is because you are using a reserved keyword `position` as your table name. If your SQL query contains a reserved keyword you can use backticks ``` "``" ``` to escape the reserved keyword.

```js
createNewOrder: (data, callBack) => {
    pool.query(`Insert into ordering (supplycontract) values (?)`, [data.supplierId], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            return callBack(error)
        }
        pool.query(`select id from ordering order by id desc limit 1`, [data.articleId], (error, results1, fields) => {
            if (error) {
                return callBack(error)
            }
            let orderid = results1[0].id;
            console.log(orderid);
            pool.query("Insert into `position` (quantity,delivery,ordering,positioninorder,articlecontract) values(?,?,?,1,?)", [data.quantity, new Date(), orderid, data.articleId], (error, results3, fields) => {
                if (error) {
                    return callBack(error)
                }
                return callBack(null, results)
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Some points to note

1. The error `Cannot set headers after they are sent` comes when you are trying to send a response twice, in simple words if you call `res.json()` or `res.status().json()` twice in one request cycle, you'll get the above error.

```js
function myController(req, res) {
  
   res.json({ status: "success" });
   res.json({ status: "success" }); // this will throw the error defined above

}
```

2. To use reserved keywords, use backticks. Or better, do not use reserved keywords.

Comment: Thank you so much! Reserved keyword was the issue! :-)

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote the answer as well. This will encourage me to engage more with the community.